# Is it cheaper to have my Cloud Run Jobs call Cloud Run Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, google-cloud-run, price

I am in the early stages of development.  I want to keep my server costs cheaper at scale.  Based on [Google Cloud Run Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing), Cloud Run Services are cheaper than Cloud Run Jobs.

I have about a dozen Cloud Run Jobs.  Would it be cheaper at scale to move those jobs to services, and just invoke them from the jobs?  Or is there an added cost of invoking the service to make it not worth it?  Or is the extra maintenance cost make it not worth it?

Or is this a case-by-case basis, and not an answerable question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is customer service-related (pricing/cost), not programming, and therefore is off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cost between Jobs and Standard (HTTP) serving is exactly the same. You can notice the price difference if you use CPU always allocated Cloud Run service.

Always allocated CPU means you pay full time for your CPU/memory. So, it's cheaper to use Cloud Run Jobs because you pay for the CPU only when your job is running. Nothing when idle. ANd no extra maintenance to wrap the job in an HTTP server.